# Socket IO. Why after join, besides you room creating still room with id equal socket.id

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have problem. After join, i get list rooms with excess room.

```
socket.join("example");
//.....
console.log(socket.rooms());
[{'ef0S2QX5mmey5LOWAAAB': { 'ef0S2QX5mmey5LOWAAAB': true } },{'example': { 'example': true } }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io automatically joins each new socket to a room with the name of its `socket.id`.  This allows you to easily send to a room when all you know is its `socket.id`.

So, you see the socket in two rooms because it's in a room with the name of its socket.id and it's in the `example` room you put it in.  In your example, `ef0S2QX5mmey5LOWAAAB` is the id for the socket.